# Should we make this question "Why are some files not movable on Windows 10?" as canonical?

Tags: discussion

I've asked this question

- [Why are some files not movable on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/q/1482018/428106)

out of curiosity and some confused it as a duplicate of

- [How can I shrink a Windows 10 partition?](https://superuser.com/q/1017764/428106)

Which was not because I was looking for the reason behind of it.

Later user [jmbpiano](https://superuser.com/users/401188/jmbpiano) [commented](https://superuser.com/questions/1482018/why-are-some-files-not-movable-on-windows-10#comment2235728_1482018) that

> This is actually a duplicate of [Why are some files unmovable when shrinking a partition in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/912198/why-are-some-files-unmovable-when-shrinking-a-partition-in-windows)? Sadly, the only "answer" at the older question fails to answer it at all. This is not a new issue, nor is it specific to Windows 10. Given the superior quality of the answers here, I'd almost be tempted to suggest removing the "windows-10" tag from this question and making it the canonical version (marking the older question as a dupe to this one).

I asked specifically for Windows 10 since I didn't want to be broad. The question went to HNQ and the answer was very good.

We can remove the windows 10 from the title (maybe with some better words from a native speaker), the answers already did not mention 10, and make this question as a canonical. Should we?

Comment: This was already done.

Comment: @Ramhound should I remove 10 from the title? Also remove windows 10 tag?

Comment: I don’t think it really matters.  The existing question has already been closed as a duplicate of the question you suggested